# Probability of a zero product given one previous zero product

Tags: probability-theory

Consider two random vectors $v=(v_1,\dots, v_n)$ and $w=(w_1,\dots, w_{n+1})$. Each element of $v$ is independently $\pm1$ with prob $1/2$.  Each element of $w$ is independently $1$ with probability $1/4$, $-1$ with probability $1/4$ and $0$ with probability $1/2$.

Let $X$ and $Y$ denote the inner product of $v$ and $(w_1,\dots,w_n)$ and the inner product of $v$ and $(w_2,\dots,w_n, w_{n+1})$ respectively, that is, $$X=\sum_{i=1}^nv_iw_i,\qquad Y=\sum_{i=1}^nv_iw_{i+1}.$$ We know that for large $n$,

$$P(X = 0)=P(Y=0) \sim \frac1{\sqrt{\pi n}}.$$

> What is $P(Y=0\mid X=0)$?

Comment: $v$ and $w$ have different dimensions and their inner product is not well-defined.

Comment: @JulianWergieluk Thank you. I just fixed that.

Comment: Why the restriction to $n$ even?

Comment: @Did It just happens to be all I need. I am happy to get rid of it if you think it makes no difference. Thank you for the edits to the question!

Comment: This looks related to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1021933).

Comment: @robjohn Yes thanks. I copied some of the notation from there which I hope is OK. I don't think it is a duplicate though. The zeros in my question seem to make it more difficult. Also that other question seems to do some sort of cyclic wrapping.

Comment: @JulianWergieluk Add zeros to complete the dimensions.

Comment: @FelixMarin There is no need to do that in this case. Hopefully the edit of Dec 10 makes this clear.

Comment: Fine. $\mbox{}$

Comment: So far, I was able to reduce the final result to
$$
{1 \over 2^{n}}\oint_{|z|\ =\ 1}\oint_{|s|\ =\ 1}
{{\mathbb E}\left[\,\prod_{k\ =\ 1}^{n}\left(\,z^{w_{k}}s^{w_{k + 1}} + z^{-w_{k}}
s^{-w_{k + 1}}\,\right)\,\right] \over zs}\quad
{{\rm d}z \over 2\pi{\rm i}}\,{{\rm d}s \over 2\pi{\rm i}}
$$
but I was unable to go any further.

Comment: @FelixMarin Would you mind explaining this a little, maybe in an answer? It looks very interesting.

Comment: I just undelete my partial answer such that you can check it.

Comment: @FelixMarin Thank you! Why did you delete it?

Comment: I felt it was not complete enough. Thanks.

Comment: @FelixMarin I think the problem is non-trivial so maybe it will inspire someone else. Unless people just won't look at  a question that already has an answer?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
Lets $\ds{{\cal V}_{j}\pars{m}}$ the probability of any $\ds{v_{j}}$ take the values $\ds{m = \pm 1}$ and $\ds{{\cal W}_{j}\pars{m}}$ the probability of any $\ds{w_{j}}$ take the values $\ds{m = -1,0,1}$ such that
$$
{\cal V}_{j}\pars{m} = \half\,,\qquad
{\cal W}_{j}\pars{m}=
{1 \over 4}\,\delta_{m,-1} + \half\,\delta_{m0} + {1 \over 4}\,\delta_{m1}
={1 \over 4}\,\delta_{m^{2},1} + \half\,\delta_{m0}
$$

> The result is given by:
>   \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large{\rm P}\pars{Y=0\mid X=0}}
> \\[5mm]&=\sum_{v_{1}\ =\ \pm 1}{\cal V}_{1}\pars{v_{1}}\ldots
> \sum_{v_{n}\ =\ \pm 1}{\cal V}_{1}\pars{v_{n}}
> \sum_{w_{1}\ =\ -1}^{1}{\cal W}_{1}\pars{w_{1}}\ldots
> \sum_{w_{n + 1}\ =\ -1}^{1}{\cal W}_{1}\pars{w_{n}}\times
> \\&\phantom{===}
> \delta_{\sum_{j\ =\ 1}^{n}v_{j}w_{j},0}\
> \delta_{\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{n}v_{k}w_{k + 1},0}
> \\[5mm]&={1 \over 2^{n}}\sum_{v_{1}\ =\ \pm 1}\ldots\sum_{v_{n}\ =\ \pm 1}
> \sum_{w_{1}\ =\ -1}^{1}{\cal W}_{1}\pars{w_{1}}\ldots
> \sum_{w_{n + 1}\ =\ -1}^{1}{\cal W}_{1}\pars{w_{n}}\times
> \\&\phantom{===--}
> \delta_{\sum_{j\ =\ 1}^{n}v_{j}w_{j},0}\
> \delta_{\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{n}v_{k}w_{k + 1},0}
> \end{align}

With the identity
$\delta_{a0}=\ds{\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over z^{1 - a}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}$:
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large{\rm P}\pars{Y=0\mid X=0}}
={1 \over 2^{n}}\sum_{v_{1}\ =\ \pm 1}\ldots\sum_{v_{n}\ =\ \pm 1}
\sum_{w_{1}\ =\ -1}^{1}{\cal W}_{1}\pars{w_{1}}\ldots
\sum_{w_{n + 1}\ =\ -1}^{1}{\cal W}_{1}\pars{w_{n}}\times
\\&\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over z^{1 - \sum_{j\ =\ 1}^{n}v_{j}w_{j}}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\oint_{\verts{s}\ =\ 1}{1 \over s^{1 - \sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{n}v_{k}w_{k + 1}}}
\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 2^{n}}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\oint_{\verts{s}\ =\ 1}
{1 \over zs}\sum_{v_{1}\ =\ \pm 1}\ldots\sum_{v_{n}\ =\ \pm 1}
\sum_{w_{1}\ =\ -1}^{1}{\cal W}_{1}\pars{w_{1}}\ldots
\sum_{w_{n + 1}\ =\ -1}^{1}{\cal W}_{1}\pars{w_{n}}\times
\\& z^{\sum_{j\ =\ 1}^{n}v_{j}w_{j}}s^{\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{n}v_{k}w_{k + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 2^{n}}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\oint_{\verts{s}\ =\ 1}
{1 \over zs}\sum_{v_{1}\ =\ \pm 1}\ldots\sum_{v_{n}\ =\ \pm 1}
\sum_{w_{1}\ =\ -1}^{1}{\cal W}_{1}\pars{w_{1}}\ldots
\sum_{w_{n + 1}\ =\ -1}^{1}{\cal W}_{1}\pars{w_{n}}\times
\\&\pars{z^{w_{1}}s^{w_{2}}}^{v_{1}}\ldots\pars{z^{w_{n}}s^{w_{n + 1}}}^{v_{n}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[5mm]&={1 \over 2^{n}}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\oint_{\verts{s}\ =\ 1}
{1 \over zs}\sum_{w_{1}\ =\ -1}^{1}{\cal W}_{1}\pars{w_{1}}\ldots
\sum_{w_{n + 1}\ =\ -1}^{1}{\cal W}_{1}\pars{w_{n}}\times
\\&\pars{z^{w_{1}}s^{w_{2}} + z^{-w_{1}}s^{-w_{2}}}\ldots
\pars{z^{w_{n}}s^{w_{n + 1}} + z^{-w_{n}}s^{-w_{n + 1}}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[1cm]&={1 \over 2^{n}}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}\oint_{\verts{s}\ =\ 1}
\\[2mm]&{{\mathbb E}\bracks{%
\pars{z^{w_{1}}s^{w_{2}} + z^{-w_{1}}s^{-w_{2}}}\ldots
\pars{z^{w_{n}}s^{w_{n + 1}} + z^{-w_{n}}s^{-w_{n + 1}}}} \over zs}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}\,{\dd s \over 2\pi\ic}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\tt\mbox{So far, I couldn't go any further}}$.