# Sum numbers game with numbers $n,n-1,n-2,\ldots,3,2,1,2,3,\ldots,n-2,n-1,n$

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle, combinatorial-game-theory

> On a line, there are $2n-1$ numbers lined up as follows:
> $$\text{$n$ , $n-1$ , $n-2$ , $\cdots$ , $3$ , $2$ , $1$ , $2$ , $3$ , $\cdots$ , $n-2$ , $n-1$ , $n$}\,.$$
> At each step, one can choose any number in the line and add it to each of its neighbours before removing it. The leftmost and rightmost numbers only have one neighbour each. The process stops when there is a single number left. What is its maximum possible value?

This problem is inspired by and a generalization of the one at http://www.micmaths.com/defis/defi_05.html where $n = 5$.

I thought that the optimal would be to start with the number at the centre and then alternate between the left and right neighbour of the previously chosen number. However, it turns out to be not optimal for $n > 3$. But I do not even know the optimal answer for $n = 5$, except that it must be at least $174$.

Comment: How did you get $174$? The maximum I was able to get was $171$.

Comment: @PuRaK: `grin` Try again! I assure you it is possible. 173 is also possible.

Comment: Ha, finally got it. So f(1)=1 , f(2)=6 , f(3)=21 , f(4)=63 , f(5)=174 as of now?

Comment: @PuRaK: Congratulations! Now can you prove that it is optimal? =D

Comment: $174$ is in fact optimal for $n=5$.  There are essentially $9!$ possible plays of the game, but you can save a factor of two by exploiting both the left-right symmetry of the initial setup, and another factor of two since the order of the last two moves doesn't matter.  This leaves $9!/4=90720$ possibilities to try, small enough to check directly.  Up to the symmetries, there's only one way to achieve $174$.

Comment: @martin: Are you sure this is exact? I'd expect it to be a (very good) approximation. Where does $n\gt 289$ come from? If this is exact, shouldn't it be exact for $n\gt216$?

Comment: @martin: I'd be interested in a proof if you have one. I expected far more smooth behaviour than what *joriki* found, so I'll not so easily assume a nice answer...

Answer (score 15):

I'm leaving the intermediate steps here so you can see how the solution developed; to summarize: The result is a hypothesis for a complete solution based on strong numerical evidence but so far without an idea how to prove its optimality. For all $n$, the solution consists of starting at some point up to $3$ slots away from (say, to the right of) the centre (exactly $3$ slots for $n\ge16$), then going outward, always alternating left and right except for sometimes going left twice in a row. The counts of alternating runs before each double left depend subtly on $n$, but they stabilize one after the other, until from $n=216$ on only the last run count changes, with the other $5$ given by $18,17,35,69,139$.

---

Continuing the successful tradition of building on Tad's answers (see [Finding real money on a strange weighing device](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341400)), I noticed that Tad's permutations always arise from interleaving an ascending and a descending sequence. There are only $2^{2n-2}$ such permutations, and since the last two elements in the permutation don't matter, there are only $2^{2n-4}$ such permutations to be tested, so I figured it made sense to systematically try all such permutations. It turns out that Tad's results are optimal among such permutations.

Here are my results; I'm repeating the ones that Tad had already obtained because I'm getting a more "canonical" form of the permutations, which might make it easier to spot patterns.

\begin{array}{ccc}
n&\text{bound}&\text{solution}\\\hline
2&6&2, 3, 1\\
3&21&4, 3, 2, 5, 1\\
4&63&5, 4, 3, 6, 2, 7, 1\\
5&174&6, 5, 4, 7, 3, 8, 2, 9, 1\\
6&466&7, 6, 5, 8, 4, 9, 3, 10, 2, 11, 1\\
7&1232&8, 7, 6, 9, 5, 10, 4, 11, 3, 12, 2, 13, 1\\
8&3239&9, 8, 7, 10, 6, 11, 5, 12, 4, 13, 3, 14, 2, 15, 1\\
9&8501&11, 10, 12, 9, 8, 13, 7, 6, 14, 5, 15, 4, 3, 16, 2, 17, 1\\
10&22502&12, 11, 13, 10, 14, 9, 8, 15, 7, 6, 16, 5, 17, 4, 3, 18, 2, 19, 1\\
11&59499&13, 12, 14, 11, 15, 10, 9, 16, 8, 17, 7, 6, 18, 5, 19, 4, 3, 20, 2, 21, 1\\
12&156678&14, 13, 15, 12, 16, 11, 10, 17, 9, 18, 8, 7, 19, 6, 20, 5, 4, 21, 3, 22, 2, 23, 1\\
13&411611&15, 14, 16, 13, 17, 12, 18, 11, 10, 19, 9, 20, 8, 7, 21, 6, 22, 5, 4, 23, 3, 24, 2, 25, 1\\
14&1082450&16, 17, 15, 18, 14, 19, 13, 12, 20, 11, 21, 10, 9, 22, 8, 23, 7, 6, 24, 5, 25, 4, 3, 26, 2, 27, 1\\
15&2850105&17, 18, 16, 19, 15, 20, 14, 13, 21, 12, 22, 11, 10, 23, 9, 24, 8, 7, 25, 6, 26, 5, 4, 27, 3, 28, 2, 29, 1\\
16&7522558&19, 18, 20, 17, 21, 16, 15, 22, 14, 23, 13, 12, 24, 11, 25, 10, 9, 26, 8, 27, 7, 6, 28, 5, 29, 4, 3, 30, 2, 31, 1\\
17&19862032&20, 19, 21, 18, 22, 17, 23, 16, 15, 24, 14, 25, 13, 12, 26, 11, 27, 10, 9, 28, 8, 29, 7, 6, 30, 5, 31, 4, 3, 32, 2, 33, 1
\end{array}

There seems to be a pattern, beginning at $n=11$, of usually alternating steps but adding an extra down step every $5$ steps, but it's not clear exactly how regular that is.

[Here's the code.](https://gist.github.com/joriki/5ae058d5d3e9458b9bbd)

*P.S.:* I checked that, beginning at $n=4$, the solution shown is the only one (up to symmetry) that's optimal among these interleaved permutations. Here are the up/down representations, to make it easier to see patterns; the last two arrows are irrelevant, I just included them to make the correspondence with the solutions in numbers above clearer.

\begin{array}{ccc}
n&\text{bound}&\text{solution}\\\hline
2&6&\uparrow\downarrow\\
3&21&\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\\
4&63&\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\\
5&174&\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\\
6&466&\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\\
7&1232&\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\\
8&3239&\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\\
9&8501&\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\\
10&22502&\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\\
11&59499&\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\\
12&156678&\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\\
13&411611&\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\\
14&1082450&\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\\
15&2850105&\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\\
16&7522558&\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\\
17&19862032&\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\\
18&52296620&\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\uparrow\downarrow\\
\end{array}

Next stage: Since the up/down pattern seems to always consist of alternating up/down with some of the downs doubled, I systematically tried all such permutations to check if the pattern that the doubling occurs every $5$ steps persists. It does not; instead, what persists from $n=15$ to $n=35$ is that there are exactly $5$ double downs.

\begin{array}{ccc}
\def\u{\uparrow}\def\d{\downarrow}
n&\text{bound}&\text{solution}\\\hline
2&6&\u\d\\
3&21&\u\d\u\d\\
4&63&\d\d\u\d\u\d\\
5&174&\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
6&466&\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
7&1232&\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
8&3239&\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
9&8501&\d\u\d\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\\
10&22502&\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\\
11&59499&\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\\
12&156678&\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
13&411611&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
14&1082450&\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\\
15&2850105&\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
16&7522558&\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\\
17&19862032&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\\
18&52296620&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
19&137319583&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
20&360144589&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
21&944521421&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
22&2477100908&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
23&6496187851&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
24&17023599948&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
25&44604984241&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
26&116811190426&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
27&305893372041&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
28&801042337577&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
29&2097687354880&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
30&5493183075966&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
31&14383060457018&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
32&37658422859324&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
33&98594676094434&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
34&258133753770289&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
35&675827901330148&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
36&1769404155218244&\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\u\d\\
\end{array}

Here are the same results (with $n=37$ added), encoded as run counts of up/down alternations separated by double downs:

\begin{array}{ccc}
n&\text{bound}&\text{solution}\\\hline
2&6&2\\
3&21&4\\
4&63&0,4\\
5&174&0,6\\
6&466&0,8\\
7&1232&0,10\\
8&3239&0,12\\
9&8501&2,1,3,4\\
10&22502&4,1,3,4\\
11&59499&4,3,3,4\\
12&156678&4,3,3,6\\
13&411611&6,3,3,6\\
14&1082450&5,3,3,3,4\\
15&2850105&5,3,3,3,6\\
16&7522558&4,3,3,3,3,4\\
17&19862032&6,3,3,3,3,4\\
18&52296620&6,3,3,3,3,6\\
19&137319583&8,3,3,3,3,6\\
20&360144589&8,3,3,5,3,6\\
21&944521421&8,3,5,3,5,6\\
22&2477100908&8,3,5,5,5,6\\
23&6496187851&8,5,5,5,5,6\\
24&17023599948&10,5,5,5,5,6\\
25&44604984241&10,5,5,5,5,8\\
26&116811190426&12,5,5,5,5,8\\
27&305893372041&12,5,5,7,5,8\\
28&801042337577&12,5,5,7,7,8\\
29&2097687354880&12,5,7,7,7,8\\
30&5493183075966&12,7,7,7,7,8\\
31&14383060457018&12,7,7,7,7,10\\
32&37658422859324&14,7,7,7,7,10\\
33&98594676094434&14,7,7,9,7,10\\
34&258133753770289&14,7,7,9,9,10\\
35&675827901330148&14,7,9,9,9,10\\
36&1769404155218244&14,9,9,9,9,10\\
37&4632452165313827&16,9,9,9,9,10\\
\end{array}

Here's a logarithmic plot of the resulting bounds over $n$, with the line corresponding to $\log(y)=0.969098n+0.278972$ fitting the results quite closely:

[image: logarithmic plot of calculated bounds over n]

Since the minimum run count never seems to decrease, I started testing only permutations with a minimum run count, staying below the actual minimum to allow for a bit of backsliding, but gradually increasing the minimum to allow for higher $n$. The *number* of runs was still free, so a solution with six double downs would have been allowed, but the possibility can't be excluded that such a solution would have had a run count below the minimum and thus would have been disregarded. Here are the results:

\begin{array}{ccc}
n&\text{bound}&\text{solution}\\\hline
38&12128128835847001&16,9,9,9,9,12\\
39&31752024718355852&16,9,9,11,9,12\\
40&83128328132235590&16,9,9,11,11,12\\
41&217633961464664291&16,9,11,11,11,12\\
42&569776076967267411&16,11,11,11,11,12\\
43&1491697805825447009&18,11,11,11,11,12\\
44&3905325498008331133&18,11,11,11,11,14\\
45&10224282933726344858&18,11,11,13,11,14\\
46&26767541287332858104&18,11,11,13,13,14\\
47&70078388001734432885&18,11,13,13,13,14\\
48&183467739835053564767&18,13,13,13,13,14\\
49&480324957118576986606&18,13,13,13,13,16\\
50&1257507207702922491305&18,13,13,15,13,16\\
51&3292196988703000057276&18,13,13,15,15,16\\
52&8619084603082606409621&18,13,15,15,15,16\\
53&22565058712862120799568&18,15,15,15,15,16\\
54&59076093869511275059946&18,15,15,15,15,18\\
55&154663224262705303376239&18,15,15,15,17,18\\
56&404913584709450796650491&18,15,15,17,17,18\\
57&1060077545022388295148722&18,15,17,17,17,18\\
58&2775319073549490260205088&18,17,17,17,17,18\\
59&7265879721619865410265014&18,17,17,17,17,20\\
60&19022320115840525778394696&18,17,17,17,19,20\\
61&49801080729814231503727780&18,17,17,19,19,20\\
62&130380922345572385311434722&18,17,19,19,19,20\\
63&341341686578978588756712358&18,17,19,19,19,22\\
64&893644137559497376528334504&18,17,19,19,21,22\\
65&2339590726811740536644613072&18,17,19,21,21,22\\
66&6125128044738931674365962964&18,17,21,21,21,22\\
67&16035793409270234188448079012&18,17,21,21,21,24\\
68&41982252184224178437539670397&18,17,21,21,23,24\\
69&109910963148283977555790730436&18,17,21,23,23,24\\
70&287750637273381498350921050654&18,17,23,23,23,24\\
71&753340948684651092999237722488&18,17,23,23,23,26\\
72&1972272208788470499474539665204&18,17,23,23,25,26\\
73&5163475677714219913350689137188&18,17,23,25,25,26\\
74&13518154824441290411576366555186&18,17,25,25,25,26\\
75&35390988795697439278822342886782&18,17,25,25,25,28\\
76&92654811562705166049135736550613&18,17,25,25,27,28\\
77&242573445892647393746991810953476&18,17,25,27,27,28\\
78&635065526115828168008464142422480&18,17,27,27,27,28\\
79&1662623132455441051432954330192870&18,17,27,27,27,30\\
80&4352803871250866057941284067804134&18,17,27,27,29,30\\
81&11395788481298729007027429355459050&18,17,27,29,29,30\\
82&29834561572649264127826347038980028&18,17,29,29,29,30\\
83&78107896236653244353987095675034922&18,17,29,29,29,32\\
84&204489127137313012297066889013936544&18,17,29,29,31,32\\
85&535359485175296566394760822973220276&18,17,29,31,31,32\\
86&1401589328388601697072447570729328594&18,17,31,31,31,32\\
87&3669408499990537951967408951471847094&18,17,31,31,31,34\\
\end{array}

It's interesting how first the $18$ and then the $17$ settle down while the remaining numbers continue to increase – that's not what I would have expected from the earlier results.

*Update:* This interesting behaviour continues. Since from $n=16$ (the first $n$ with five double downs) the next run count tuple could always be obtained by changing some of the run counts by $\pm2$ (in fact, with the sole exception of $n=20\rightarrow n=21$, it could always be obtained by adding $2$ to one of the run counts), I now narrowed the search to such increments. The result is rather surprising (to me). One run count after the other stabilizes, until from $n=216$ on only the last run count changes, that is, the beginning of the solution is fixed, with $5$ double downs in specific places, and after that it's only alternating up/down. I checked that this remains so up to $n=5000$. Thus, despite the sometimes somewhat erratic changes in the run counts at lower $n$, the results yield a plausible hypothesis for a complete solution to the game. To summarize, the assumptions that would have to be validated to prove this hypothesis are that (up to symmetry)

1. beyond $n=12$, the solution continues to result from interleaving an ascending and a descending sequence;
2. beyond $n=18$, the solution continues to consist of alternating ascents and descents, except for some double descents;
3. beyond $n=37$, the minimum of the run counts of alternating runs does not sharply decrease;
4. beyond $n=87$, the number of double descents remains $5$, and the run counts only change by $\pm2$; and
5. beyond $n=216$, only the last run count changes.

The resulting payoffs are very well described by $\log y\simeq0.962445n+0.451906$; the deviation is not visible in a plot for $n$ up to $1000$.

Here are the complete run counts for this hypothesized solution, up to the point at which only the last run count keeps changing:

\begin{array}{cc}
n&\text{solution}\\\hline
2&2\\
3&4\\
4&0,4\\
5&0,6\\
6&0,8\\
7&0,10\\
8&0,12\\
9&2,1,3,4\\
10&4,1,3,4\\
11&4,3,3,4\\
12&4,3,3,6\\
13&6,3,3,6\\
14&5,3,3,3,4\\
15&5,3,3,3,6\\
16&4,3,3,3,3,4\\
17&6,3,3,3,3,4\\
18&6,3,3,3,3,6\\
19&8,3,3,3,3,6\\
20&8,3,3,5,3,6\\
21&8,3,5,3,5,6\\
22&8,3,5,5,5,6\\
23&8,5,5,5,5,6\\
24&10,5,5,5,5,6\\
25&10,5,5,5,5,8\\
26&12,5,5,5,5,8\\
27&12,5,5,7,5,8\\
28&12,5,5,7,7,8\\
29&12,5,7,7,7,8\\
30&12,7,7,7,7,8\\
31&12,7,7,7,7,10\\
32&14,7,7,7,7,10\\
33&14,7,7,9,7,10\\
34&14,7,7,9,9,10\\
35&14,7,9,9,9,10\\
36&14,9,9,9,9,10\\
37&16,9,9,9,9,10\\
38&16,9,9,9,9,12\\
39&16,9,9,11,9,12\\
40&16,9,9,11,11,12\\
41&16,9,11,11,11,12\\
42&16,11,11,11,11,12\\
43&18,11,11,11,11,12\\
44&18,11,11,11,11,14\\
45&18,11,11,13,11,14\\
46&18,11,11,13,13,14\\
47&18,11,13,13,13,14\\
48&18,13,13,13,13,14\\
49&18,13,13,13,13,16\\
50&18,13,13,15,13,16\\
51&18,13,13,15,15,16\\
52&18,13,15,15,15,16\\
53&18,15,15,15,15,16\\
54&18,15,15,15,15,18\\
55&18,15,15,15,17,18\\
56&18,15,15,17,17,18\\
57&18,15,17,17,17,18\\
58&18,17,17,17,17,18\\
59&18,17,17,17,17,20\\
60&18,17,17,17,19,20\\
61&18,17,17,19,19,20\\
62&18,17,19,19,19,20\\
63&18,17,19,19,19,22\\
64&18,17,19,19,21,22\\
65&18,17,19,21,21,22\\
66&18,17,21,21,21,22\\
67&18,17,21,21,21,24\\
68&18,17,21,21,23,24\\
69&18,17,21,23,23,24\\
70&18,17,23,23,23,24\\
71&18,17,23,23,23,26\\
72&18,17,23,23,25,26\\
73&18,17,23,25,25,26\\
74&18,17,25,25,25,26\\
75&18,17,25,25,25,28\\
76&18,17,25,25,27,28\\
77&18,17,25,27,27,28\\
78&18,17,27,27,27,28\\
79&18,17,27,27,27,30\\
80&18,17,27,27,29,30\\
81&18,17,27,29,29,30\\
82&18,17,29,29,29,30\\
83&18,17,29,29,29,32\\
84&18,17,29,29,31,32\\
85&18,17,29,31,31,32\\
86&18,17,31,31,31,32\\
87&18,17,31,31,31,34\\
88&18,17,31,31,33,34\\
89&18,17,31,33,33,34\\
90&18,17,33,33,33,34\\
91&18,17,33,33,33,36\\
92&18,17,33,33,35,36\\
93&18,17,33,35,35,36\\
94&18,17,33,35,35,38\\
95&18,17,35,35,35,38\\
96&18,17,35,35,37,38\\
97&18,17,35,37,37,38\\
98&18,17,35,37,37,40\\
99&18,17,35,37,39,40\\
100&18,17,35,39,39,40\\
101&18,17,35,39,39,42\\
102&18,17,35,39,41,42\\
103&18,17,35,41,41,42\\
104&18,17,35,41,41,44\\
105&18,17,35,41,43,44\\
106&18,17,35,43,43,44\\
107&18,17,35,43,43,46\\
108&18,17,35,43,45,46\\
109&18,17,35,45,45,46\\
110&18,17,35,45,45,48\\
111&18,17,35,45,47,48\\
112&18,17,35,47,47,48\\
113&18,17,35,47,47,50\\
114&18,17,35,47,49,50\\
115&18,17,35,49,49,50\\
116&18,17,35,49,49,52\\
117&18,17,35,49,51,52\\
118&18,17,35,51,51,52\\
119&18,17,35,51,51,54\\
120&18,17,35,51,53,54\\
121&18,17,35,53,53,54\\
122&18,17,35,53,53,56\\
123&18,17,35,53,55,56\\
124&18,17,35,55,55,56\\
125&18,17,35,55,55,58\\
126&18,17,35,55,57,58\\
127&18,17,35,57,57,58\\
128&18,17,35,57,57,60\\
129&18,17,35,57,59,60\\
130&18,17,35,59,59,60\\
131&18,17,35,59,59,62\\
132&18,17,35,59,61,62\\
133&18,17,35,61,61,62\\
134&18,17,35,61,61,64\\
135&18,17,35,61,63,64\\
136&18,17,35,63,63,64\\
137&18,17,35,63,63,66\\
138&18,17,35,63,65,66\\
139&18,17,35,65,65,66\\
140&18,17,35,65,65,68\\
141&18,17,35,65,67,68\\
142&18,17,35,67,67,68\\
143&18,17,35,67,67,70\\
144&18,17,35,67,69,70\\
145&18,17,35,69,69,70\\
146&18,17,35,69,69,72\\
147&18,17,35,69,71,72\\
148&18,17,35,69,71,74\\
149&18,17,35,69,73,74\\
150&18,17,35,69,73,76\\
151&18,17,35,69,75,76\\
152&18,17,35,69,75,78\\
153&18,17,35,69,77,78\\
154&18,17,35,69,77,80\\
155&18,17,35,69,79,80\\
156&18,17,35,69,79,82\\
157&18,17,35,69,81,82\\
158&18,17,35,69,81,84\\
159&18,17,35,69,83,84\\
160&18,17,35,69,83,86\\
161&18,17,35,69,85,86\\
162&18,17,35,69,85,88\\
163&18,17,35,69,87,88\\
164&18,17,35,69,87,90\\
165&18,17,35,69,89,90\\
166&18,17,35,69,89,92\\
167&18,17,35,69,91,92\\
168&18,17,35,69,91,94\\
169&18,17,35,69,93,94\\
170&18,17,35,69,93,96\\
171&18,17,35,69,95,96\\
172&18,17,35,69,95,98\\
173&18,17,35,69,97,98\\
174&18,17,35,69,97,100\\
175&18,17,35,69,99,100\\
176&18,17,35,69,99,102\\
177&18,17,35,69,101,102\\
178&18,17,35,69,101,104\\
179&18,17,35,69,103,104\\
180&18,17,35,69,103,106\\
181&18,17,35,69,105,106\\
182&18,17,35,69,105,108\\
183&18,17,35,69,107,108\\
184&18,17,35,69,107,110\\
185&18,17,35,69,109,110\\
186&18,17,35,69,109,112\\
187&18,17,35,69,111,112\\
188&18,17,35,69,111,114\\
189&18,17,35,69,113,114\\
190&18,17,35,69,113,116\\
191&18,17,35,69,115,116\\
192&18,17,35,69,115,118\\
193&18,17,35,69,117,118\\
194&18,17,35,69,117,120\\
195&18,17,35,69,119,120\\
196&18,17,35,69,119,122\\
197&18,17,35,69,121,122\\
198&18,17,35,69,121,124\\
199&18,17,35,69,123,124\\
200&18,17,35,69,123,126\\
201&18,17,35,69,125,126\\
202&18,17,35,69,125,128\\
203&18,17,35,69,127,128\\
204&18,17,35,69,127,130\\
205&18,17,35,69,129,130\\
206&18,17,35,69,129,132\\
207&18,17,35,69,131,132\\
208&18,17,35,69,131,134\\
209&18,17,35,69,133,134\\
210&18,17,35,69,133,136\\
211&18,17,35,69,135,136\\
212&18,17,35,69,135,138\\
213&18,17,35,69,137,138\\
214&18,17,35,69,137,140\\
215&18,17,35,69,137,142\\
216&18,17,35,69,139,142\\
\end{array}

*P.P.S.:*

We can get the exact growth rate of the payoff from a recurrence relation. Beyond $n=216$, the beginning of the game is always the same, and the end consists in a pure run of alternating moves. Assume that the last two numbers left standing in the game for $n$ are $a_n$ and $b_n$. Then the game for $n+1$ reaches a point where the four numbers

$$n+1\quad a_n\quad b_n\quad n+1$$

are left, and we combine them into

$$a_n+n+1\quad a_n+b_n\quad n+1$$

and then into

$$2a_n+b_n+n+1\quad a_n+b_n+n+1\;.$$

So

$$
\pmatrix{a_{n+1}\\b_{n+1}}=\pmatrix{2&1\\1&1}\pmatrix{a_n\\b_n}+\pmatrix{n+1\\n+1}\;.
$$

The larger of the eigenvalues of the matrix is $(3+\sqrt5)\,/\,2$, with logarithm $0.962424$ in good agreement with the fitted solution.

*And one more thing:* This perspective also explains why there are only ever a few double descents. If we always alternate, the weight of every number in the payoff is a Fibonacci number; the weight of the first number is $F_{2n-1}$. (The growth rate $(3+\sqrt5)\,/\,2$ is the square of the Fibonacci growth rate, the golden section $(1+\sqrt5)\,/\,2$.) Every double descent costs a bit of this exponential growth. (A more detailed analysis might quantify how much.) So it doesn't pay to incur another double descent just to shift the first number from, say, $4$ to $5$, but it does pay to shift it slightly away from $1$, since significant factors can be gained by that. An attempt at proving the optimality of the solution should probably go in this direction.

*Update:*

I brought the numerical results quite a bit closer to a rigorous proof. I'm now making only the assumptions that nothing interesting happens at very high $n$ and that the solution interleaves an ascending and a descending sequence, that is, it starts somewhere and then eats its way to the margins to the right and left, but with no assumptions about when it goes left or right. Thus, in terms of my numbered list of assumptions above, I'm only making assumptions $1$ and $5$ and dropped the complicated assumptions $2$ through $4$.

On that basis, the solutions up to $n$ in the thousands can quickly be determined using [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), as in [this code](https://gist.github.com/joriki/b23c00c6f70c07c7d512). A record is kept for each interval $[m,n]$ of the "best" ways of reducing that interval to the border points $m$ and $n$, i.e. the "best" sequences of moves in the interior of the interval without playing either $m$ or $n$. The reason for the scare quotes around "best" is that the result is characterized by the two values that $m$ and $n$ end up with, and such pairs of values aren't necessarily comparable. The code keeps track of all pairs that aren't dominated by another pair. The iteration is initialized with intervals $[m,m+1]$ without interior, whose value pairs are simply the pair of initial values at $m$ and $m+1$, and then updated by growing each interval either to the left or the right, collecting results and discarding the dominated ones.

When all intervals in the game for some $n_{\text{max}}$ have been treated, the solutions for all $n\le n_{\text{max}}$ can be read off. I ran this up to $n_{\text{max}}=870$, and the results coincided with the previous ones, showing that the assumptions $2$ to $4$ were justified.

A proof of assumption $1$ might proceed by considering a complete move sequence as a set of alternating sequences like the ones considered here, which meet at their borders from time to time. One would then have to show that the result achieved by two sequences meeting is dominated by the result that could have been achieved by playing the joint interval in a single alternating sequence. This is complicated by the fact that at the time the sequences meet, they don't immediately merge into two points, so results characterized by three or four values may have to be considered. Assumption $5$ might be amenable to some form of asymptotic analysis.

Comment: Yes I suspected such an optimal solution after looking at his answers, and so even more I expect an elegant proof! =D

Comment: More precisely, I expect there to be some recurrence that describes the optimal solution and explains why it is largely alternating but presumably the irregularities are due to something like boundary conditions..

Comment: By the way I had recently seen that question you linked to. It was amazing and quite counter-intuitive! Yet I didn't realize that it was the same @Tad!

Comment: @martin: You can take the irregular ones from the first table (I guess you did), and beyond $n=16$ they always increase by $1$ (since the number of double descents no longer changes). (I just noticed that my solution for $n=3$, where there's more than one solution , changed from one table to another; sorry if that threw you off. From $n=4$, where there's only one solution up to symmetry, everything should be consistent.)

Comment: @joriki yes, got them thanks! *PPS* is great stuff BTW :)

Comment: Much more complicated than I thought... I don't have much hope for an elegant solution anymore, but I still hope there is an efficient recursive solution.

Comment: @user21820: My last update (at the end of the answer) cleans things up a bit; it does away with the more complicated assumptions and allows the solutions for $n$ up to thousands to be calculated quite efficiently on the basis of one simple assumption.

Comment: Nice! I'll just give you the (tiny) bounty. I didn't expect anyone to put in as much time and effort into the problem as you did. I hope you had enough fun to compensate!

Comment: @user21820: I did :-) And I'd suggest to wait with the bounty in case someone finds a rigorous proof. (I'm not going to be pursuing it any further myself.)

Comment: Oops too late. Never mind I can always put out another bounty another time. =)

Comment: @user21820: Thanks :-)

Comment: @joriki sorry, little question. Is $n=216$ $3043737865392529335770470541025871672010375549729353293110808740740516902574043810672779690?$

Comment: @joriki I know you don't intend to pursue this, but [this array plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hA7dD.png) of your results to n=216, together with the possibility that those 5 strands are the only ones that appear, suggest you might be close to an absolute on the last double arrow ...

Comment: @martin: It is -- well done :-)

Comment: @martin: Wow, that's a nice plot :-) What do mean by "close to an absolute on the last double arrow"?

Comment: @joriki well, you said that beyond n=216, only the last run count changes. I was thinking maybe the last run count might hit a ceiling soon? (judging by that array plot) ...

Comment: @martin: No -- that might have been the case before my last update, because I'd restricted it to five double descents, but the new code in the last update doesn't have that restriction, so we know for a fact that there are only five double descents all the way up to $n=870$ (and I could easily check further). And if the number of double descents doesn't change, one of those six run counts has to increase, so the last one can't hit a ceiling. Also note my remark starting "And one more thing", where I try to explain why it makes sense that nothing changes after this.

Comment: @joriki great.- thanks for extended insight into this :)

Comment: @martin: (This is in response to a comment now deleted.) In the new update, I needed only two assumptions for the completeness of this solution -- one is that there are no unexpected changes at very high $n$, which is irrelevant for these "low"-$n$ results; the other is that the solution has the form of starting somewhere and then eating one's way to both margins in arbitrary order. So under that assumption, which seems very reasonable and held true in Tad's full searches up to $n=12$, my results are now certain to be optimal.

Comment: Up to bugs, of course, but since I rewrote the code from scratch for the dynamic programming version and got the same results, those seem unlikely.

Comment: @joriki thanks for the detailed reply :) I hope this answer gets the attention it deserves!

Comment: @joriki I think the last count will keep on going up by 2 at a time. I think the penultimate count might hit a ceiling though. Am I barking up the wrong tree (don't know how to run java to test with your code)? I am thinking it might happen very shortly after 216. I don't suppose you could post a higher result in the form $18,17,35,69,139,142$ if you have it? If not, don't worry - I am sure you are tired of it by now!

Comment: @martin: That's what I meant, yes; sorry if that wasn't clear. The penultimate count hits its cealing at $n=216$, and after that the last count increases by $2$. I guess I should have made the table a few lines longer to show that.

Comment: @joriki Ah! It makes sense now! Thanks :)

Comment: @martin: About Java: what sort of machine are you on? It usually comes preinstalled on a Mac. If you only have a runtime but no compiler, I could send you the compiled code. If you think you might use Java more than once, you could consider installing Eclipse.

Comment: @joriki that's a great idea - I only mess around in Mathematica - never used Java before ... should probably take the plunge ... re machine, just crappy old pc (Dell laptop).

Comment: @joriki compiled code would be great :)

Comment: @martin: This is the compiled code for the dynamic progamming version: https://www.dropbox.com/s/32ae7exeocopluw/sums.zip?dl=0. You still need a Java runtime to run it, though :-) It should run for a couple of seconds and then output the values of the games up to $n=1000$.

Comment: @joriki brilliant! thank you :) I will have a go at setting up Java runtime - possibly opening a can of worms here ;)

Comment: @martin: Well, it should be, it's got about $10000$ factors of $(3+\sqrt5)\,/\,2$ :-) I took me a bit to calculate that because I was being so wasteful of space; I had to do some more recycling... but eventually I got the same result.

Comment: @joriki `lowerB[nn_] := DifferenceRoot[Function[{y, n}, {-4 - n + y[n] - 3 y[1 + n] + y[2 + n] == 0, y[1] == 6, y[2] == 21, y[3] == 63}]][nn - 1]` isn't bad for a lower (not optimal) bound too - predicts $n=10^6$ has $\approx 417976$ decimal digits. In fact, it looks as though most numbers have $\approx 0.417976 n$ digits, but that is a fairly rough guess. - Agrees-ish with your $\log$ estimate :)

Comment: @martin: Interesting. Makes sense, since that recurrence has the same eigenvalue, $(3+\sqrt5)\,/\,2$. How did you come up with it?

Comment: @joriki Yes! I notice that earlier after you added your *PPS* section! It is based on optimal strategy up to $n=9,$

Comment: @martin: Considering that I once translated a book about Mathematica, I understand surprisingly little of that :-)

Comment: @joriki [This](https://github.com/martinq321/question1341929/blob/master/some%20functions) should be clearer ... I'll delete the unreadable code-comments

Comment: @joriki strategy is really basic (don't know why I overcomplicated things in code!) - it is just based on pattern $n,n-1,n-2,n-2,n-3,n-3,n-4,n-4,\dots$ and then reordered using `reduC1[list_] := {list[[1]]}~ Join~(redU1[list, #] & /@ Range[2, Length@list])` on it. This gives same optimal sequences up to $n=8$ and then falls behind a bit. Still, is fairly good lower bound, since it can be easily reproduced via difference equation :)

Comment: @joriki I tried running the `.class` file, but not luck (have never done this before). I have `Question1341929Complete$Record.class`, `Question1341929Complete$RecordSet.class` and `Question1341929Complete.class` in the zip file. Do I need a `.java` file too? Sorry for all the questions! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25775/discussion-between-joriki-and-martin).

Comment: @joriki thanks for the reply on my attempt! Interesting experiment though - I feel I understand it a bit better now - interesting that payoff is not that much greater :)

Comment: @joriki BTW any chance that ratio could have a closed form as $n\rightarrow\infty$ - or have I got the wrong idea again?!

Comment: @martin: It does. Beyond $n=216$, it's the same recurrence relation being applied to both pairs of results, with different "initial" values; you can solve that in closed form, and then that ratio is just the quotient of the sums of the two pairs. In that form it won't be quite obvious that it's a ratio of two integers, though, because the eigenvalues are irrational.

Comment: @martin: Sorry, I overlooked your "as $n\to\infty$" -- yes, that limit is the ratio of the coefficients of the eigenvector corresponding to the larger eigenvalue (which you can take at any $n\ge216$ because it doesn't change beyond $216$). So compute $(a_{216},b_{216})$ for both strategies, decompose that with respect to the eigensystem of the recurrence matrix, and form the ratio of the coefficients corresponding to the larger eigenvalue.

Comment: @joriki great! Thanks for your help on this :)

Comment: joriki, see new Meta post on this by the person asking. If you both are willing, there would appear to be sufficient reason to correspond by email.  http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21042/unresolved-problem-from-comments-based-on-another-users-question

Comment: @WillJagy: I'm willing :-) How does that work? Do I post my address, or is there some official way of doing this? (And thanks for the note!)

Comment: joriki, got your email and replied. Unable to say what time zone martin is in, that is one area where I think anonymity is a real inconvenience.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some lower bounds; I computed these by simulated annealing.  The notation is best understood by thinking about the problem as follows: at each step, you pick a nonzero number in the line, add it to its nearest nonzero neighbors, and zero it out.  So, for $n=3$, a game might run
$$ (3,2,1,2,3) \to (3,3,0,3,3)\to (6,0,0,6,3)\to (12,0,0,0,9)\to(21,0,0,0,0).$$
You can encode this game as the permutation $\pi=\{3,2,4,5,1\}$, where we zero out position $i$ at step $i$ for $i<2n-1$; $\pi(2n-1)$ is the location of the final number.

With this notation, here are the best scores I was able to achieve for small values of $n$.

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \textrm{bound} & \textrm{solution}\\
\hline
 2 & 6 & \{2,3,1\} \\
 3 & 21 & \{2,3,4,5,1\} \\
 4 & 63 & \{5, 4, 3, 6, 2, 7, 1\} \\
 5 & 174 & \{ 6,5,4,7,3,8,2,1,9\} \\
 6 & 466 & \{7, 6, 5, 8, 4, 9, 3, 10, 2, 1, 11\}  \\
 7 & 1232 &\{ 6, 7, 8, 5, 9, 4, 10, 3, 11, 2, 12, 13, 1 \} \\
 8 & 3239 & \{9, 8, 7, 10, 6, 11, 5, 12, 4, 13, 3, 14, 2, 1, 15\} \\
 9 & 8501 & \{7, 8, 6, 9, 10, 5, 11, 12, 4, 13, 3, 14, 15, 2, 16, 1, 17\}  \\
 10 & 22502 & \{12, 11, 13, 10, 14, 9, 8, 15, 7, 6, 16, 5, 17, 4, 3, 18, 2, 1, 19\}  \\
 11 & 59499 & \{9, 10, 8, 11, 7, 12, 13, 6, 14, 5, 15, 16, 4, 17, 3, 18, 19, 2, 20, 1, 21\} \\
 12 & 156678 & \{10, 11, 9, 12, 8, 13, 14, 7, 15, 6, 16, 17, 5, 18, 4, 19, 20, 3, 21, 2, 22, 1, 23\}\\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: @Martin do you mean I've computed the scores incorrectly? Or you've found better solutions?

Comment: @martin I included the patterns so they can be verified.  They should be correct, but very possibly suboptimal.

Comment: able to reproduce your results now - not sure if optimal either, but can't beat them! +1 :)

Comment: Thanks for your experiments! Though I'm looking for proven optimal solutions, yours already disproves the class of solutions that I thought would include the optimal one.

Comment: @Tad: Nice starter! (+1) I think we can better see what's going on, if the indexes are shifted from $[1, 2n-1]$ to $[-n,n]$. This way we obtain for $n=5, \{1,0,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4\}$.